# Read file to variable in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, file, variables

I want to be able to put a file to a variable so I can interact with it. For example I could put a wav file into a variable and play it back without having to distribute the separate file. Is this possible for instance by using Base64. I have seen some Python programs for example that have images embedded in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could conceivably store the contents of a binary .wav file as a static, uuencoded text array.

Probably a better way to go about it would be to create a "resource" for your binary data:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbx3z216.aspx